# Can the jsoup tag be associated with Java?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, syntax-highlighting

Can we please set the default syntax highlighter of the [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup) tag to Java? I've seen lots of questions tagged only [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup), with code that doesn't get highlighted because people don't specify the highlighter or the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag.

Comment: (While I agree with you, I feel the need to point out that these should be retagged +[java].)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done now.

Keep in mind that it's often worth adding the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag to [jsoup](/questions/tagged/jsoup) questions that don't already have it, especially if they primarily involve Java code, since they often do anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Good point on the java tag, will do.